# Selecting 7th Person (row) and get 7 as result

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I want to select the 7th person (Pierre Gasly (for example)) [Score list Season F1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJfHN.jpg), so I can return number 7 in my C# application.

```
SELECT CONCAT(strVoorNaam, strTussenVoegsel, ' ',  strAchterNaam) AS Naam, SUM(CAST(tblPunten.strScore AS INT)) AS score
FROM tblPunten
JOIN tblPuntenCoureur ON tblPuntenCoureur.PuntenID = tblPunten.ID
JOIN tblPersoon ON tblPersoon.ID = tblPuntenCoureur.PersoonID
JOIN tblSeizoen ON tblSeizoen.ID = tblPuntenCoureur.SeizoenID
WHERE tblPunten.ID != 12 AND tblPunten.ID != 13 AND  tblPunten.ID != 14 AND  tblPunten.ID != 15
AND  tblPunten.ID != 16 AND  tblPunten.ID != 17 AND  tblPunten.ID != 18 AND  tblPunten.ID != 19 AND tblSeizoen.intJaartal = 2019 
GROUP BY CONCAT(strVoorNaam, strTussenVoegsel, ' ',  strAchterNaam), tblPersoon.strAchterNaam
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a row limiting clause:

```
select 
    concat(strvoornaam, strtussenvoegsel, ' ',  strachternaam) as naam, 
    sum(cast(pu.strscore as int)) as score
from tblpunten pu
join tblpuntencoureur pc on pc.puntenid = pu.id
join tblpersoon pe on pe.id = pc.persoonid
join tblseizoen se on se.id = pc.seizoenid
where pu.id not between 12 and 19 and se.intjaartal = 2019 
group by strvoornaam, strtussenvoegsel, strachternaam, pe.strachternaam
order by score desc
offset 6 rows fetch next 1 row only
```

This gives you the seventh row in the resultset.

Side notes:

- table aliases help keeping the query concise and easier to write
- you should be qualifying *all* columns that come into play in the query

On the other hand, if you are trying to get the rank of a specific person, then that's different. You can use `rank()` instead:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        concat(strvoornaam, strtussenvoegsel, ' ',  strachternaam) as naam, 
        sum(cast(pu.strscore as int)) as score,
        rank() over(order by sum(cast(pu.strscore as int)) desc) rn
    from tblpunten pu
    join tblpuntencoureur pc on pc.puntenid = pu.id
    join tblpersoon pe on pe.id = pc.persoonid
    join tblseizoen se on se.id = pc.seizoenid
    where pu.id not between 12 and 19 and se.intjaartal = 2019 
    group by strvoornaam, strtussenvoegsel, strachternaam, pe.strachternaam
) t
where naam = 'Pierre Gasly'
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I dont get 7 as a result now.